# Standalone <AutocompleteInput /> in <Filter /> gives Error

Tags: react-admin

Having a standalone (without ReferenceInput) AutocompleteInput or SelectInput being fed choices from an external function in Filters results in "TypeError: selectedIds.includes is not a function" when selecting a choice.

```
<Filter {...props}>
    <AutocompleteInput label="Company Name" source="company.id" optionText="name" optionValue="id" choices={getDataReferenceInput("company", props.resource)} {...props}/>
</Filter>
```

getDataReferenceInput() returns data as
`[ { id: 1, name:"a company name" }, { id: 2, name:"another company name"}]` which correlates with the optionText and optionValue

How can I fix this TypeError, I've been stumped for weeks on this problem ?

Thank you very much for any help/ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the {...props} inside the Autocompleteinput that was causing this issue...

Removed it and now everything works perfectly